# Conditional Probability 5 numbers in box, probability the 5 numbers chosen are in order

Tags: probability

This is for my high school probability and statistics class. The question is there are 5 balls numbers 1-5 in a box what is the probability of choosing them in order of largest to smallest 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

Comment: what I got is 1/5 * 1/4 * 1/3 * 1/2 * 1

Comment: This is correct!

Comment: Can you show me how to do it using conditional probability?

Comment: @jack That *is* done by conditional probability.  $${P(B_1{=}5)}{P(B_2{=}4\mid B_1{=}5)}{P(B_3{=}3\mid (B_1,B_2){=}(5,4))}{P(B_4=2\mid (B_1,B_2,B_3){=}(5,4,3))}{P(B_5=1\mid(B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4){=}(5,4,3,2))} \\ = {\tfrac 15\cdot\tfrac 14\cdot \tfrac 13\cdot \tfrac 12\cdot \tfrac 11}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability to draw the $5$ balls in the desired order is $$\frac{1}{5!}=\frac{1}{120}=\color\green {0.00833}$$

We do not need the conditional probability, but if you want to do it this way : If we have drawn the right ball in the first try, we have now probability $\frac{1}{4}$ to draw the right ball again and so on, giving the expression you mentioned.

Comment: The *odds* are $1: (5!-1) = 1:119$ .

Comment: @GrahamKemp Fixed.